# Android Studio When clicking on imageview reduce time from the timer

Tags: java, android, timer

This is the first time I am posting something on StackOverflow and that it only because I felt like this is one of those times I was not able to find what I needed from the vast Internet!

I am currently making an Android Application that is a game where I have an ball that is an imageview and each time I click on the ball, it moves to a random location with this method I've built:

```
private void changePos() {
    RelativeLayout gameLayout = findViewById(R.id.gameFrame);
    int frameHeight = gameLayout.getHeight();
    int frameWidth = gameLayout.getWidth();

    Random ballLocationY = new Random();
    int ballY = ballLocationY.nextInt(frameHeight);

    Random ballLocationX = new Random();
    int ballX = ballLocationX.nextInt(frameWidth);

    gameLayout.setY(ballY);
    gameLayout.setX(ballX);
}
```

So what I am struggling with is to reduce the timer with each click.
What I am trying to do is to reduce the timer with each click on the ball by a certain percentage.

Basically each time the user clicks on the ball, the timer starts off from 0 and counting upwards in seconds and milliseconds, and at 3 second mark the game is over.

This is the approach I am playing around with:

```
Runnable updateThreadTimer = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        timeInMilliseconds = System.Clock.uptimeMillis() - startTime();
        updateTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
        int secs = (int) (updateTime / 1000);
        countDownText.setText("" + String.format("%2d", secs) + ":"
                                 + String.format("%3d", timeInMilliseconds));
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);

        if (secs == 3 && timeInMilliseconds >= 3000) {
             timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
             mHandler.removeCallbacks(updateThreadTimer);   
        }
    }
}
```

Variables necessary:

```
long startTime = 0L, timeInMilliseconds = 0L, timeSwapBuff = 0L, updateTime = 0L;

Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

And then I have this in the Overridden onCreate method:

```
ball.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
         if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             changePos();
             startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
             mHandler.postDelayed(updateThreadTimer, 0);
         }
         return true;
    }
}
```

So what I get is a timer that gets reset to 0 with each click on the button and starts again. And the timer displays in seconds and milliseconds: 0:0000, which is what I wanted, but I wanna reduce a certain percentage with each click and update the time. 
So let's say the counter starts with 3 seconds limit, after clicking on the ball couple of times, the timer should eventually come down and the game should fail if the timer goes above that time.

Obviously I have simplified the code quite a lot to get straight to the point.
I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how I could approach the problem I have.

I also want to apologize if the question is not asked properly, being the first time posting, leave suggestions if theres any hatin' going on!

And I also want to mention it one more time, I've looked around for a solution like this, and the code I have put together is from lots of different sources, so I feel like I've done my research, and not being able to find something, hence I am turning to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess I am going to answer my own question as I have solved it now and also in hope that this may solve problems for some.

I redid some parts of the code and scratched the Runnable way, instead I took an approach that uses CountDownTimer class.

```
private long currentTime;
private long maxTimer = 3000;
private double fivePercent = .05;
private CountDownTimer myTimer = null; 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Some code...

    // Assign 3000 to currentTime
    currentTime = maxTimer;

    ball.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (myTimer != null) {
                        // Cancel timer
                        myTimer.cancel();
                        // Calculating 5 % from maxTimer
                        long a = (long) (maxTimer * fivePercent);
                        maxTimer -= a;
                        // Storing new maxTimer in currentTime     
                        currentTime = maxTimer;
                    }

                   myTimer = new CountDownTimer(currentTime, 1) {
                       @Override
                       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                           countDownText.setText("Time: " + String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
                           currentTime = millisUntilFinished;
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onFinish() {
                           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultsActivity.class);
                           GameActivity.this.startActivity(intent); 
                       }
                   }.start();

               changePos();
               scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score++ + "");
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

I have simplified the code for demonstration purpose, but basically what I did was to create a CountDownTimer, and whenever I click on the ball, the CountDownTimer will get cancelled, and invoke a new one, before creating a new CountDownTimer it will calculate off 5 % and put the result into the new CountDownTimer.